# OpenCSV what if I have '|' as a seperator instrad of ','

Tags: java, opencsv

My code is this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader("C://Users//himanshurai//eclipse-workspace//nike.csv")).withSeparator('|').withSkipLines(1).build();
List<TShirt> tShirtList = reader.readAll().stream().map(data -> {
    //TShirt tShirt = new TShirt(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7]);
    TShirt tShirt = new TShirt();
    tShirt.setId(data[0]);
    tShirt.setName(data[1]);
    tShirt.setColor(data[2]);
    tShirt.setGender(data[3]);
    tShirt.setSize(data[4]);
    tShirt.setPrice(data[5]);
    tShirt.setRating(data[6]);
    tShirt.setIsAvailable(data[7]);
    return tShirt;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
tShirtList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

And this is my CSV file:

[image]

My code is showing an Index out of bound error. I think it is because the CSV file has '|' as a separator instead of ',' and I tried to use withSeperator('|') method but it is showing error like  the method is undefined. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Spelling error.  Try `withSeparator` ... with 2 As.

Comment: (They should make Latin mandatory for all undergraduates.  Separate comes from Latin *se-* and *pararer*.)

Comment: That is really funny.  Anyway, here is the javadoc link: https://javadoc.io/static/com.opencsv/opencsv/3.2/com/opencsv/CSVParserBuilder.html#getSeparator().  As you can see, they use the correct spelling in the javadoc ... and the method name in the API.

Comment: @StephenC it's still not working, I tried again with correct spelling

Comment: But it is not telling you that `withSeparator` is undefined ... is it.   What is it actually telling you now?

Comment: @StephenC it is undefined for CSVReaderBuilder, if it won't work is there any other way for this

Comment: Actually ... that javadoc looks messed up.

Comment: @StephenC everything is working except for it is showing out of bound exception, so now I'm trying to give the program to read custom separator and this is what I'm failing to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.  So, in addition to the original spelling error, I think you are getting the `CSVParserBuilder` and `CSVReaderBuilder` classes mixed up.

According to the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/CSVReaderBuilder.java), you should be using them like this:

```
final CSVParser parser =
    new CSVParserBuilder()
   .withSeparator('\t')
   .withIgnoreQuotations(true)
   .build();
final CSVReader reader =
    new CSVReaderBuilder(new StringReader(csv))
   .withSkipLines(1)
   .withCSVParser(parser)
   .build();
```

Notice that the `withSeparator` method is on `CSVParserBuilder` not `CSVReaderBuilder`.

(When I looked carefully ... the javadoc that I found [here](https://javadoc.io/static/com.opencsv/opencsv/3.2/com/opencsv/CSVParserBuilder.html) doesn't match the source code.  It shows `withSeparator` in the example, but not in the method list.  Go figure.)